# Targeting android mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, user-agent, tablet

Is this possible?

I want to exclude android phones from using some code, but I still want it to work on android tablets.

The only user agent I can find is "android" which will obviously exclude everything android related.

Comment: Don't sniff devices, test for functionality and base your test on screen size or device capability, not user agent string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can proceed:

1. Exclude the code at runtime, knowing the size of user's device. The actual width and height in pixels can simply be queried at runtime.
2. Since there exists a multiple apk support, which means that you can publish a set of apk's targeting different devices, you can create two versions of your application, each targeting its set of devices.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of solely relying on user agent to detect Android devices. Some devices are lying. An example is HTC sensation, that does not give out it is an android device, but rather Mac OS X device. There could be others too.

Also width and height on android devices are sometimes reported incorrectly or inconsistently. My colleague struggled to get aspect ratio right on different Android devices because of that.

For Android tablets I would suggest looking for Android/3.x substring in user agent. As only tablets use this particular version of Android. All phones are either 2.3.x or 4.0 Androids.

It can become more complicated in future, when both tablets and phones use Ice Cream Sandwich.